# Shell script: how to use getopts to get last arguments and unhandle arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, archlinux

There is a program named [cower](https://github.com/falconindy/cower). ([cower](https://github.com/falconindy/cower) is an Archlinux AUR downloader.)

```
cower -[udhsc] target
```

I am write a shell script named [xcower](https://gist.github.com/911090).

```
xcower -[Syudhsc] target1 target2 target3 ...
```

[xcower](https://gist.github.com/911090) take 2 additional parameter S and y. and pass the remained arguments to cower. I don't know how to get remain arguments and targets.

BTW, [xcower](https://gist.github.com/911090) goals is install AUR packages from fresh installed Arch in 1 command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try using `shift` and combination of `OPTIND` variable eg (not answer)

```
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
```

From bash reference

> OPTIND The index of the next argument
>   to be processed by the getopts builtin
>   command (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS
>   below).
>
> shift [n]
>                 The  positional  parameters  from  n+1  ... are renamed
>   to $1 ....  Parameters represented by
>   the numbers $# down to $#-n+1 are
>                 unset